# GoogleMap v2 is not being displayed when wifi turned off

Tags: android

I am using GoogleMap v2 API in my application. When I do a fresh install and I am connected to wifi, the Google map loads and displays fine in my fragment. If however, I do a fresh install and I am not connected to a wifi network, the map never gets displayed. The code below executes exactly the same in both cases and no errors are shown in the logcat:

In my onCreateView:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         Log.d("MAP", "on activity created");
         googleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
         if (googleMap != null) {
              Log.d("MAP", "google map not null");
//                    initializeGoogleMap();
         } else {
              Log.d("MAP", "google map null");
         }
    }
};
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
```

Output with wifi on (map displayed):

```
D/MAP﹕ on activity created
D/MAP﹕ google map not null
```

Output with wifi off (map not displayed):

```
D/MAP﹕ on activity created
D/MAP﹕ google map not null
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to rectify this issue? At the moment I'm stumped. Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have any other Internet connection sources ? if so, are you sure that Internet connection is actually available (not just "connected to network" but you can actually receive data (test with making a simple HTTP request to your favorite website for example).

Comment: @mithrop, Internet connection is definitely available on the wifi network. Could it be that the map can only be  displayed when the user is connected to the internet and not when on 3G/H ?

Comment: that was my question : do you have any other Internet source when you turn off your wifi. And are you sure you 3G/H is "working correctly" ?

Comment: Yes it is, I can make service calls using my mobile data @mithrop

Comment: any idea about the "connection speed" or connection quality ?

Comment: Possible duplicates :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772918/google-map-update-with-wifi-but-not-with-3g
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742461/google-static-map-issue-not-displaying

Comment: Try regenerating your API KEY and change in manifest, It might work

Comment: @mithrop, Connection quality is about three bars, I think I will try using the signed api key

Comment: @Jayanth, Thanks, thats how I got it in the first place, and accepted answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing is working, then you could also check if you have restricted the background data of Google Play Services. If you have, try to uncheck the restriction and then try again... More info about how to "unrestrict" the background data [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1663315?hl=en).

Hope this helps...

Comment: I may have to to hurt myself now.. Thanks a million for pointing this out!!